# Do I need a separate class file for each web method when calling from objective-c?

Tags: .net, objective-c, web-services

I am a little confused about how to handle a web service result in objective-c...

I want to put all my web service calls in one class file name webservices.h,.m

but every web method shares the same delegate for dataReceived and parsing XML.

How do I know which result is for which call if they all exists in one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can definitely do this. Just have different instances of "web services," such as NSURLConnection and compare the connection passed to the delegate method to your instance. So an example of using multiple NSURLConnections in one class:

in webservices.h:

```
NSURLConnection *connection1;
NSURLConnection *connection2;
NSMutableData *receivedData1;
NSMutableData *receivedData2;
```

in webservices.m:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  if (connection == connection1) {
    [receivedData1 appendData:data];
  } else if (connection == connection2) {
    [receivedData2 appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: Is that the best way to do this? How is everyone else implementing this?  So if my webservice.asmx has 10 web method, then I would need 10 connection instance in my webservice.m class?  Is there anything in the connection object that I can use to compare?

Comment: To my knowledge this is the only way to do it asynchronously in a single class file (you could of course reuse an NSURLConnection object if you loaded your services sequentially, but that would be slower). Note you also need separate NSMutableData instances to receive the data, otherwise you risk writing multiple service returns to the same data object.